# Error with installation of python-binance

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, installation, binance

I can't seem to install python-binance without running into an error.
[image: python-binance install error message]

Comment: Please do not use images for textual information!

Answer (score 1):

To install to the current user use, the `--user` switch. Example, `pip install --user python-binance`

[PIP documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#id25) for further reading. You may also type `pip install --help` for more options relating to the install command.